# How to upload PDF, DOC, DOCX file to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

I created a form which uploads information to the database. Now I am at a point where people can upload PDF, DOC or DOCX files. However how do I do this with the code I have?

My upload.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "usbw";
$dbname = "persons";

// CREATE A CONNECTION WITH THE DATABASE
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

// ADDRESS APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO address (address_street, address_housenumber, 
                                         address_zipcode, address_city, address_state)
                    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $straat, $huisnummer, $postcode, $stad, $provincie);

$straat = htmlspecialchars($_POST[straat]);
$huisnummer = htmlspecialchars($_POST[huisnummer]);
$postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST[postcode]);
$stad = htmlspecialchars($_POST[stad]);
$provincie = htmlspecialchars($_POST[provincie]);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === FALSE) {
die("Error: " . $stmt->error);
}

// CAPTURE LAST INSERTED address_id
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;

// PERSON APPEND - PREPARE SQL STATEMENT AND BIND PARAMS
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO person (person_firstname, person_lastname, 
                                        person_email, person_phonenumber,
                                        person_cv, person_address)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssi", $firstname, $lastname, $email, $telephone, $cv, $last_id);

$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST[firstname]);
$lastname = htmlspecialchars($_POST[lastname]);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST[email]);
$telephone = htmlspecialchars($_POST[telephone]);
$cv = htmlspecialchars($_POST[cv]);

// EXECUTE STATEMENT
$result = $stmt->execute();    
if ($result === TRUE) {
$URL="http://localhost:8080/Website/bedankt.php";  
header ("Location: $URL");  
} else {
echo "Error: " . $stmt->error;
}

$stmt->close();
$conn->close();

?>
```

The field person_CV is used to store file attachment PDF, DOC and DOCX only. In my database I used a varchar(45) type because I want to upload the file to a directory on my server. But if you have any suggestions you would recommend I would use that one.

My form

```
 <form method="post" action="functie.php">
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="firstname" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Voornaam" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="lastname" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Achternaam" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="straat" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Straat" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="huisnummer" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Huisnummer" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="postcode" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Postcode" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="stad" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Stad" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">

                        <select name="provincie"  id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Provincie" required>
                        <option value="Drenthe">Drenthe</option>
                        <option value="Flevoland">Flevoland</option>
                        <option value="Friesland">Friesland</option>
                        <option value="Gelderland">Gelderland</option>
                        <option value="Groningen">Groningen</option>
                        <option value="Limburg">Limburg</option>
                        <option value="Noord-Brabant">Noord-Brabant</option>
                        <option value="Noord-Holland">Noord-Holland</option>
                        <option value="Overijssel">Overijssel</option>
                        <option value="Utrecht">Utrecht</option>
                        <option value="Zeeland">Zeeland</option>
                        <option value="Zuid-Holland">Zuid-Holland</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="telephone" id="telephone" class="form-control" type="tel" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="email" id="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input name="cv" id="cv" class="form-control" type="file" placeholder="CV">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-form" name="submit" value="Solliciteer"/>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" value="Nieuwe sollicitatie slimme-meters-maken.nl" name="subject" id="subject">
                </form>
```

Comment: Hard to say; is that cv file coming from a form to be uploaded? files require a valid enctype/post method which is unknown. Files is `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`. post your html form.

Comment: That's what I thought... Is it possible that a form can have two actions? my form action right now is functie.php.but adding a upload.php with a file upload would be great.

Comment: as suspected; you're missing an enctype for it. error reporting would have helped you here also. and yes, it is possible but why do you need 2 actions?

Comment: That way I have one file for just a file upload and one for other information. Like I said you'd recommend anything better I would take a look at the option. I am new to PHP so I am trying to figure things out.

Comment: If you want to use 2 actions, you can have 2 differently named submit buttons (using `isset()` for either) and use a conditional statement to check if a file is included. To upload, see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php it's all in there with examples.